# Sum of Fourier Series for $f(t) = (t+1) \cos t$ at $t = 3\pi$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

So I have this question here (I write out the whole question):

If $f(t)=(t+1)\cos (t)$ for $-\pi < t < \pi$, what is the sum for the Fourier series for $f(t)$ at $t=3 \pi$?

My solution is this:

**IF** the function is $2\pi$-periodic I can just calculate the mean value of $f(-\pi)$ and $f(\pi)$ since the Fourier series converge to the mean value at discontinuities, right? That is also the answer stated in the Solution manual. But how do I know that function is in fact $2\pi$-periodic? How do I know that the function doesn't have any other properties at the intervalls outside this one? I am just asking this to be sure that I'm not thinking to hard about things like this..

Comment: The FS is $2\pi$-periodic by construction.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Sure.  Write the FS for $f$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$.  What is the period of the FS representation?

Comment: See my comment on the first answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Dr. MV's comment, consider a Fourier series for $f$ on $-L<x<L$,

$$f(x) = \sum_\limits{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{i n \pi x/L}$$

What's the period of the extended series? Now what if $L=\pi$ as in your case - what's the period?

---

When you restrict the sum's domain to $[-L,L]$ you get $f$ on that interval, which recreates the original function. Note that the length of this interval is $2L$.

When you loosen the restriction, such as to define the sum for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ , the RHS's periodicity comes into play. It will periodically map out $f$ in "chunks" of length $2L$.

Comment: Yes this i understand, but the information in the question doesn't tell me that the series repeat itself outside this interval? There is nothing like $f(t)=f(t+2\pi)$, maybe that isn't needed?

Comment: @Danny Danny, if you extend the FS representation outside of $[-L,L]$, what is its period?

Comment: The original function defined along the entire real line need not be periodic. You only care about the portion from $[-\pi,\pi]$. The way that the Fourier series is built is periodic. It will take your interval and repeat it, again and again.

Comment: Oh okay! So it doesn't matter if the function look totally different outside this region, because that is not the part we are interested in anyway. Is that correct understod? I know how the FS works with periods and all that, my question was regarding the original function $f(t)$ :)

Comment: Yeah. When we specify $f(t)$ such that $t \in [-\pi,\pi]$, the function *doesn't exist* outside the interval. It abruptly halts at either endpoint. This is technically a completely different function than $f(t)$ s.t. $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so no need to worry about it.

Comment: Now I understand it.. Now it doesn't even make sense to talk about something outside that interval. Thanks for clearing things up for me :)